# Is there command to grant Full Disk Access for specific application?

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, settings, privacy

You can allow an application to access data if you change settings in
`Security & Privacy` → `Privacy` → `Full Disk Access`.

Is there command to accomplish the same in terminal?

Comment: It seems we are all waiting for the documentation that describes this functionality. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107546

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

No, this must be performed by the user through the System Preferences page. Any method to do this via the command line would likely be considered a bug and should be reported.

You can also do this through Mobile Device Management, but this isn't suitable for individuals since your device probably isn't managed. Read more about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol).

Comment: Actually it is common in macos for most operations to be able to be done via the command-line and there is no reason whatsoever why this one should be different.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Do you have a sample command that accomplishes this?

Comment: No, not yet I'm afraid.  For my own purposes I was able to learn that one can drag any program file from any Finder window and drop it onto the System Preferences "Full Disk Access" pane.  It's tedious, e.g. for granting everything in `/etc/shells`, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [article for Admins on the Apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210595) that mentions how to handle this:

To use the `systemsetup` command with either the `-setremotelogin` or `-setremoteappleevents` flag in macOS Catalina 10.15 or later, first give the parent process full-disk-access. You can grant full-disk-access manually or using Mobile Device Management (MDM):

- Manually grant Full Disk Access: choose Apple menu  > System
  Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then select the Privacy tab.
  Scroll down and click Full Disk Access, then add the parent process.Use
- MDM: use the PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl payload.

For more information about its usage, see the `systemsetup(8)` man page.

Comment: Although the solution may be found at this link at Apple, it is possible that the link may fail to work at some time in the future, making your answer eventually useless. Please take some time brazenly copying and pasting some of the details from this Apple page into your answer so the OP can get a sense of wat to do, and don't forget to attribute Apple as the source.

Comment: This seems to set system-wide configuration options, rather than application-specific settings for the TCC privacy database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't seem to work out exactly how to use PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl with an MDM (e.g. Mosyle) to enable full disk required to allow me to enable sshd via MDM. Could you update the answer with an example?

Comment: This is completely unhelpful and wrong and does not answer the question.  The referenced article is only about how to allow `systemsetup` to be used.

Comment: Yeah, the article says to grant `systemsetup` full disk access, not that `systemsetup` can grant it.