# Trash file inaccessible through Terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, trash

Having come from a Linux environment, I am accustomed to using the command line, as in MacOS's "Terminal". In particular, I know about permissions, "sudo" and such.

But I am unable to perform any operations whatsoever via the command line on the .Trash file in my home directory. (I do have admin privileges on the machine.) I can "ls -al" my home directory...

However, I *can* see (and copy, deleted, etc.) the contents of my .Trash file via Finder, and could apparently manipulate its permissions. But, seemingly, nothing I can do with finder makes .Trash accessible via Terminal.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Yes, it's a protected folder.  Give Terminal full disk access.

Comment: @MarcWilson, I seem unable to figure out on my own what "giving Terminal full disk access" would mean. Advise, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Googling about how to "give Terminal full disk access", led me to another answer on this site, [Is there command to grant Full Disk Access for specific application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351632/is-there-command-to-grant-full-disk-access-for-specific-application)

The wording was not obvious to me. :)

To repeat that other answer: under **System Preferences** > **Security and Privacy**, one of the sub-headings *is* **Full System Access**, with a list of potential parent processes that may or may not be granted this. So I added "Terminal.app" there (did not have to figure out how to type in a suitable format, but, rather, could choose from a list).

Testing: this does allow me (without `sudo` but as user with admin privileges), to `ls .Trash`, remove files, etc.

EDIT: "problem" solved, though I *could* already manipulate nearly every other file on the machine via `sudo`, so the recalcitrance of `.Trash` was one-of-a-kind (according to my expectations, anyway).

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to see your own .Trash - as for other directories without Full DIsk Access try anything outside you $HOME and ~/Library

Comment: @mmmmmm, yes, I could see my own .Trash through Finder, but not through Terminal or Aquamacs...

Comment: My comment was about your comment re not sudo

Comment: Ah, thx, ... :)